# My Code just doesn't work, how do I fix it?

Tags: python, calculator

Basicly I just made a Calculator Code (it should probably work) but is just shows the Ascii Art **CALC** but doesn't actually run the Calculator Code, no error or anything, just doesn't run a **Part of Code** for some Reason. -_-
(The Ascii Art in the Code may look messy but actually its ok in the cmd)

```
import time
from colorama import init, Fore
init()

print(Fore.CYAN)
print("  _______     ____     ___          _______")
print(" /       |   /    \\   |   |        /       |")
print("|    ____/  /  /\\  \\  |   |       |    ____/")
print("|   |      |  /  \\  | |   |       |   |")
print("|   |      |  ¯¯¯¯  | |   |       |   |")
print("|   |      |   __   | |   |       |   |")
print("|    ¯¯¯¯\\ |  |  |  | |   ¯¯¯¯¯¯\\ |    ¯¯¯¯\\")
print(" \\       | |  |  |  | |         |  \\       | U L A T O R  //made by dot.")
print("  ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯   ¯¯    ¯¯   ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯    ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯")
print(Fore.WHITE)

def start():
    func = input("\n+ - * / : ")
    p = input("Math Problem: ")
    pl_ps = p.split(" + ")
    mi_ps = p.split(" - ")
    mu_ps = p.split(" * ")
    di_ps = p.split(" / ")
    if func == "+":
        one = int(pl_ps[0])
        two = int(pl_ps[1])
        answer = one + two
        print(answer)
    elif func == "-":
        one = int(mi_ps[0])
        two = int(mi_ps[1])
        answer = one - two
        print(answer)
    elif func == "\*":
        one = int(mu_ps[0])
        two = int(mu_ps[1])
        answer = one * two
        print(answer)
    else:
        if func == "/":
            one = int(di_ps[0])
            two = int(di_ps[1])
            answer = one / two
            print(answer)
        else:
            print("The option " + '"'+func+'"' + " does not exist.")
def e():
    exit = input("Restart(r),Exit(e): ")
    if exit == "r":
        start()
    else:
        if exit == "e":
            print("Closing Programm...")
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            print("The option " + '"'+exit+'"' + " does not exist.")
            time.sleep(1)
            e()
```

Comment: you never call your functions. they don't run if they don't get called.

Answer (score 2):

You never call your functions. They don't automatically run if they don't get called.
So you can call it like `yourfuncname()`.

```
import time
from colorama import init, Fore
init()

print(Fore.CYAN)
print("  _______     ____     ___          _______")
print(" /       |   /    \\   |   |        /       |")
print("|    ____/  /  /\\  \\  |   |       |    ____/")
print("|   |      |  /  \\  | |   |       |   |")
print("|   |      |  ¯¯¯¯  | |   |       |   |")
print("|   |      |   __   | |   |       |   |")
print("|    ¯¯¯¯\\ |  |  |  | |   ¯¯¯¯¯¯\\ |    ¯¯¯¯\\")
print(" \\       | |  |  |  | |         |  \\       | U L A T O R  //made by dot.")
print("  ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯   ¯¯    ¯¯   ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯    ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯")
print(Fore.WHITE)

def start():
    func = input("\n+ - * / : ")
    p = input("Math Problem: ")
    pl_ps = p.split(" + ")
    mi_ps = p.split(" - ")
    mu_ps = p.split(" * ")
    di_ps = p.split(" / ")
    if func == "+":
        one = int(pl_ps[0])
        two = int(pl_ps[1])
        answer = one + two
        print(answer)
    elif func == "-":
        one = int(mi_ps[0])
        two = int(mi_ps[1])
        answer = one - two
        print(answer)
    elif func == "\*":
        one = int(mu_ps[0])
        two = int(mu_ps[1])
        answer = one * two
        print(answer)
    else:
        if func == "/":
            one = int(di_ps[0])
            two = int(di_ps[1])
            answer = one / two
            print(answer)
        else:
            print("The option " + '"'+func+'"' + " does not exist.")
def e():
    exit = input("Restart(r),Exit(e): ")
    if exit == "r":
        start()
    else:
        if exit == "e":
            print("Closing Programm...")
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            print("The option " + '"'+exit+'"' + " does not exist.")
            time.sleep(1)
            e()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
    e()
```

Comment: Better yet, guard with `if __name__ == "__main__":` so it can be a library too.

Comment: @GregSchmit Ah, good idea. edited. thanks

Answer (score 0):

how are you running your script? Is it being called by another script or are you running this script directly? If the latter, you never called `start()`